# List or better Algorithm for random C# - Unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, random

I am working with C# in Unity3D (2018.3.0f2) and I need to create a random function with multiple outcomes and multiple parameters. Is there any better way? Mine works, but I would like to have it in a list and if possible shorter.

```
float rndFloat = Random.value;

if      (rndFloat <  0.33f)  occlusionTime = 0.3f;
else if (rndFloat >= 0.33f && rndFloat < 0.66f) occlusionTime = 0.7f;
else                                            occlusionTime = 1.1f;

rndFloat = Random.value;

if (rndFloat < 0.25f)
{
    BallEnd.transform.position = EndPositions[0];
    endPosPixelCoords = EndPositionsPixel[0];
}

if (rndFloat >= 0.25f && rndFloat < 0.5f)
{
    BallEnd.transform.position = EndPositions[1];
    endPosPixelCoords = EndPositionsPixel[1];
}

if (rndFloat >= 0.5f && rndFloat < 0.75f)
{
    BallEnd.transform.position = EndPositions[2];
    endPosPixelCoords = EndPositionsPixel[2];
}

if (rndFloat >= 0.75f)
{
    BallEnd.transform.position = EndPositions[3];
    endPosPixelCoords = EndPositionsPixel[3];
}
```

Comment: in java it is possible to shuffle an arraylist with the method "shuffle()", but in C# there is no such method available.

Comment: http://www.vcskicks.com/randomize_array.php

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle

Comment: If their chances are equal, `var result = list[Random.Range(0, list.Count)];` will work.

Comment: Try search for "random with weight", where you can randomize things base on the proc.